# Why would an equation render on preview and in an external TeX compiler, but not in post?

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown-preview

I know the general phenomenon is that rendering of previews differs from rendering of posts, but, presumably, the goal is to minimise unnecessary discrepancies—and that, in particular, non-esoteric TeX, in an "I know it when I see it" sense, that renders in an external compiler without special packages should render in posts.

The following equation appears in [@SidharthGhoshal's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/451475) to [Is there a summation method where the divergent series $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\dots$ converges to a finite value(V2)?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/451471):

```
U_n = M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)-M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\label{1}\tag{$U$} = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} -  \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}} 
 = m_0 \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}}  \right) = m_0 c \left( \frac{n+2}{\sqrt{2c(n+2) -1 }} - \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{2c(n+1)-1}}  \right) =
```

I have to admit that I haven't been patient enough to count that braces and `\left(\right)` pairs match, but it seems to me, if they didn't, then this shouldn't render at all anywhere—and it renders just fine in preview:

[image: Equation rendering in preview]
and in an external TeX compiler; but it doesn't render in the post:

[image: Equation not rendering in post]

Sometimes such errors can be fixed on refresh, but that doesn't seem to be happening to me.

Comment: The preview only users an answer. I would guess that the problem might be that both the question and the answer contain `\label{1}\tag{$U$}` - but the problem that the same label is used twice on one page only manifests when both the question and the answer are displayed. This is what I [recently edited](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/451475/revisions).

Comment: This post on [math.meta.se] seems to be about a problem caused by the same thing: 
[Equations not shown, as if there is a problem with MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32825).

Comment: There is no point in the equation having a label at all, as it is never referenced (and there is no reason it ever should be, in such a short post).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5718/why-would-an-equation-render-on-preview-and-in-an-external-tex-compiler-but-not#comment28889_5718), while each person has their own labelling preferences, I think that argument is easy to accept; but I think it is also probably orthogonal to the question—whether, as @‍MartinSleziak [suggests](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5719), the problem is *caused* by the label probably has little to do with whether the label *belongs*.

Comment: Thank you for asking this. I was wondering the same and never got around to it! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a CW answer - for experimenting.

Here is the equation copy-pasted from the (current revision of the) post:

$$ U_n = M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)-M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\label{1}\tag{$U$} = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} -  \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}} 
 = m_0 \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}}  \right) = m_0 c \left( \frac{n+2}{\sqrt{2c(n+2) -1 }} - \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{2c(n+1)-1}}  \right) =   $$

Here is the same question after omitting `\label{1}\tag{$U$}`

$$ U_n = M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)-M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} -  \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}} 
 = m_0 \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}}  \right) = m_0 c \left( \frac{n+2}{\sqrt{2c(n+2) -1 }} - \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{2c(n+1)-1}}  \right) =   $$

And here `\label{1}\tag{$U$}` was replaced by `\label{2}\tag{U}`

$$ U_n = M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)-M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\label{2}\tag{U} = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} -  \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}} 
 = m_0 \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}}  \right) = m_0 c \left( \frac{n+2}{\sqrt{2c(n+2) -1 }} - \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{2c(n+1)-1}}  \right) =   $$

When I copy-paste the very first equation once again - the one containing `\label{1}\tag{$U$}` - this one is not rendered correctly. Which suggests this might be some problem with duplicate label.

$$ U_n = M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)-M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\label{1}\tag{$U$} = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} -  \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}} 
 = m_0 \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}}  \right) = m_0 c \left( \frac{n+2}{\sqrt{2c(n+2) -1 }} - \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{2c(n+1)-1}}  \right) =   $$

Comment: "this might be some problem with duplicate label"—oh, that makes perfect sense!  I was so focussed on the post in isolation that I forgot that labels are per-page things.  It also makes sense of why things would be fine on preview—the 'other' U label isn't there yet.  Thank you!

Comment: I would encourage users to use more expressive labels (not just `1`, for example).  In fact, including their userID or something unique to them would help.  E.g., `\label{LSpice-1}` rather than `\label{1}` would be a useful way to avoid label clashes.

Comment: Of course, the `\tag` can be anything you want, it is the `\label` that is causing the expression to fail.

Comment: @DavideCervone, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5718/why-would-an-equation-render-on-preview-and-in-an-external-tex-compiler-but-not#comment28893_5719), I look forward to everyone labelling their equations `LSpice-1`.  (@‍IosifPinelis has the interesting approach of numbering equations by 10s, in the hope of avoiding conflicts.)

Comment: @DavideCervone I wonder whether `\label{1}` appears in some standard help file. Otherwise I can't understand why so many users are automatically putting it in all their tagged equations even though they do not use the `\label`-`\ref` facility at all.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I am not able to find anywhere that that is suggested.  But I suppose they are doing it to make the label match the tag, which they probably start at equation number 1 (even if other answers already include an equation numbered 1).

Comment: @LSpice, no doubt you are right, now everyone will use `LSpice-1` instead of `1`.  Sigh.

Comment: @DavideCervone I almost never use `\label` in MathJax - so here I was basically just trying what works without really understanding what I'm doing. And this post was meant as a "sandbox" for testing - not as a genuine answer.
Would you perhaps be willing to post an answer explaining at least basic dos and don'ts concerning `\label`, `\tag` (and maybe some related commands)?  (Or maybe some brief explanation with a link to some documentation - if something suitable is available on https://www.mathjax.org/ or elsewhere.)

Comment: [Re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5718/why-would-an-equation-render-on-preview-and-in-an-external-tex-compiler-but-not#comment28913_5719), I second @‍MartinSleziak's suggestion/request.  I'm not sure which answer would then be appropriate to accept, but I doubt @DavideCervone or @‍MartinSleziak would be much fussed either way.  (Amusingly, I note that all of @‍DavideCervone's [answers](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3A38515+is%3Aanswer) here are to my questions. )